# With plugin-list-category-post is there a way of sorting titles by a date?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I have a series of posts that fall within a  category of "calendar".  I want to produce a list of them in date order.  The post titles can begin with the date but I can't see a way of sorting by it.  Being British, I'd prefer something in the format dd/mm/yy and I guess North American users would prefer mm/dd/yy.  At the moment, the only way I can achieve this is using the format yy/mm/dd which few people can understand.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Many thanks, Graham.

Comment: To be clear: sorting by post creation time will not work here? (`[catlist orderby=date]`) This is a calendar of future events?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but you could create your own template and then reformat the date.

start by creating a folder `list-category-posts` in your theme directory. copy the `default.php` template there from the plugin's templates folder, and rename it `custom.php`, or whatever you'd like.

within that custom.php file, find the line:

```
//Show the title and link to the post:
$lcp_display_output .= $this->get_post_title($single);
```

and replace it with:

```
//Show the title and link to the post:

$temp_title = $this->get_post_title($single);

preg_match("/\<a.*href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*)\<\/a\>+/", $temp_title, $matches);

$temp_date = substr($matches[2], 0, 10);
$new_title = substr($matches[2], 11);

$timestamp = strtotime($temp_date);
$new_date = date("j F, Y", $timestamp);

$lcp_display_output .= '<a href="' . $matches[1] . '">' . $new_title . ' - ' . $new_date . '</a>';
```

For this to work, your posts should be titled:

> YYYY/MM/DD Event title

If the day or month is a single digit, it MUST have a leading zero.

The reformatted result will be:

> Event title - 9 September, 2011

The part that's reformatting the date is here:

```
$new_date = date("j F, Y", $timestamp);
```

If you want to change this, have a look at [PHP's Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for your options.

The last line is reassembling the various bits back together, you can change the order of title - date as well as the hyphen separating them if you'd like.

The shortcode to load your custom.php template and sort by title is:

```
[catlist name=calendar template=custom orderby=title]
```